# MAC OS - Terminal command to set JAR program to run at startup?

Tags: java, macos, jar, startup

This is where MAC OS stores its start-up items,

/Library/LaunchAgents

How to set a JAR program from Terminal to run at startup? Also how to remove existing program from startup?

I need to use either Terminal or any other script code to add JAR program to load at startup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [launchd: Managing a Java Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32927956/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [launchd: Managing a Java Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927956/launchd-managing-a-java-jar)

Answer (score 1):

- Write a bash script that runs your JAR.

  #!/bin/bash

  java -jar /path/to/my/jar
- Create a .plist entry in /Library/LaunchAgents as shown [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156443/running-a-simple-shell-script-on-startup-in-yosemite)